# Order in the Windows Explorer context menu

Tags: windows, contextmenu

How can I change the order of the entries in the context menu?(e.g. for Directories) I need to know how Windows determines the order when showing that so I can control it. For example I want to place my custom action at the end of the context menu list

Thank in advance!

Comment: I'm sorry for the pun. I though that the second link (http://windowsxp.mvps.org/context_folders.htm) would help you along.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My Google-fu led me to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/freeassociations/archive/2005/05/19/420208.aspx):

> So the sorting is based on the following elements in decision order:
>
> 1. Key priority (eg, txtfile, *, AFSO)
> 2. Registry Enumeration order of shellex\contextmenuhandlers with a special case for static verbs always being first
> 3. IContextMenu Implementation order
>
> So if there is any contention for position, there is no consistent way for an extension to guarantee their relative position within the menu.

Obviously you can't do anything about phase 1.  Phase 3 only applies to the verbs implemented in your handler.  That leaves phase 2.  The only thing you can do is name your entry under ContextMenuHandlers such that it would be enumerated first, but nothing's stopping someone else from doing the same thing.

Comment: Microsoft is always mucking with their systems.  Here's the archived version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/freeassociations/how-do-explorer-context-menus-sort-verbs

Answer (score 6):

This is for Windows 7, maybe same for newer versions. It was inspired by the other answers, all is affecting the order.

*I'm explaining entries for "*" (all files), but the same goes for special extensions.*

**I take no responsibility for any changes made in registry!**

There are three sections in the context menu, as it says in [How to Change the Order of Options in Context Menu](http://techoqueries.blogspot.se/2012/08/how-to-change-order-of-options-in.html) (from [answer by @Anonymouse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37966605/1526010))

They call them:

```
2 - Default menu position (at the top).
1 - Send to, copy to folder and move to folder menu part (in the middle).
0 - Rename menu part (at the bottom).
```

Within these sections the position is decided by the rules in [answer by @Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7013950/1526010)
The easiest way to change the order within the "section" is to change the name of the registry key under `HKCR-*-shell` or `HKCR-*-shellex`. All under subkey `shell` will be before them under `shellex`. Keys that have the `CLSID` as the key name will be as last entry since they are last in the used order.

As an example, I was following a [sample from MSDN to build a Context Menu Handler](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CppShellExtContextMenuHandl-410a709a)
**EDIT 2021-04-14:**
The MSDN link is no longer valid, it redirects to a "Browse code samples" page. You can search there for `Context menu sample`, but the one I followed seems to have been removed.
The closest to the old one I followed [is perhaps this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/contextmenu/)

The one I followed is using the `CLSID` as the name for the key under `shellex`, and a "friendly name" as default value. It was placed at the bottom of "section" 2 (top section). I changed the key name to something like `Asample` and changed the default value to be the `CLSID` instead. Now it was directly after entries under `shell`.

There are some more ways of changing the order.

For keys under `shell` you can add the value `Position` with string data `Top` or `Bottom`. Not possible to decide in what "section".

For keys under `shellex` the value `Position` has no effect. Instead it's possible to decide in what "section" the entry will be using `flags`, [described in the link](http://techoqueries.blogspot.se/2012/08/how-to-change-order-of-options-in.html) above.

> 1. Use the `CLSID` for the shellext you want to move. It's like
>    `{XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX}`. Get it either from the key name or the default value, it depends on how the entry is done.
> 2. Find the entry under HKCR-CLSID, the key has the name of the `CLSID`.
> 3. Add a value with name `flags` and data `DWORD` with the "section" number described above under the found `CLSID`.

Comment: The MSDN link has evaporated.

Comment: Thanks @user30478, I have updated the answer. But I couldn't find the old example I was following.

Answer (score 3):

This did it for me... Steps 4 through 7 - setting the "flags"
http://techoqueries.blogspot.de/2012/08/how-to-change-order-of-options-in.html

Answer (score 2):

[This Q&A](https://superuser.com/questions/749529/add-open-containing-folder-to-context-menu) shows a simple way to CREATE (not move) an item within the context menu. I managed to duplicate an existing item. Then I moved my item to a higher and more accessible position within the context menu, by renaming the key to start with something "aMyItem" or "0MyItem".

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to find a way to re-order things, it irritates me that the daily use options are pushed to the end, when obscure utilities you might use once in a blue moon are filling up the top of the list.

I found a lazy way to do this, using a little utility package called "Windows 10 Manager" [Windows 10 Manager](https://www.yamicsoft.com/windows10manager/product.html) - it's a few quid, but it's a lot easier than registry hacking.  It can't do everything, but it does let you add items into the top section at least - and also to suppress cheeky ones that installed themselves in there without asking.[image: Example showing amended context menu]

As you can see, it's actually *duplicated* some entries rather than moving them, but never mind.