# Windows Shell: Add custom context menu to a specified position

Tags: windows, contextmenu, shell-extensions

I'm working on a custom context menu, and I was able to register it and it shows in the file explorer, but I want to put it next to another existed context menu.

[image]

But the position is not what I want. I want to put it another position:

[image]

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

Add the source code here:

It's a sample downloaded from: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/583726/Writing-a-shell-extension-in-plain-Cplusplus

ShellExt.cpp

```cpp
// ShellExt.cpp: implementation of the CShellExt class.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <shlobj.h>

#include "ShellExt.h"
#include "Guid.h"

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Construction/Destruction
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CShellExt::CShellExt()
{

}

CShellExt::~CShellExt()
{

}

STDMETHODIMP_(DWORD) CShellExt::Release(void)
{
    if(--m_ObjRefCount == 0)
    {
        delete this;
        return 0;
    }

    return m_ObjRefCount;
}

STDMETHODIMP_(DWORD) CShellExt::AddRef(void)
{
    return ++m_ObjRefCount;
}

STDMETHODIMP CShellExt::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, LPVOID *ppReturn )
{
    *ppReturn = NULL;

    if( IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IUnknown) )
        *ppReturn = this;
    else if( IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IClassFactory) )
        *ppReturn = (IClassFactory*)this;
    else if ( IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IShellExtInit))
        *ppReturn = (IShellExtInit*)this;
    else if ( IsEqualIID(riid, IID_IContextMenu))
        *ppReturn = (IContextMenu*)this;


    if( *ppReturn )
    {
        LPUNKNOWN pUnk = (LPUNKNOWN)(*ppReturn);
        pUnk->AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }

    return E_NOINTERFACE;
}

STDMETHODIMP CShellExt::Initialize (
    LPCITEMIDLIST pidlFolder, LPDATAOBJECT pDataObj, HKEY hProgID )
{
    FORMATETC fmt = { CF_HDROP, NULL, DVASPECT_CONTENT, -1, TYMED_HGLOBAL };
    STGMEDIUM stg = { TYMED_HGLOBAL };
    HDROP     hDrop;

    // Look for CF_HDROP data in the data object.
    if ( FAILED( pDataObj->GetData ( &fmt, &stg ) ))
    {
        // Nope! Return an "invalid argument" error back to Explorer.
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    // Get a pointer to the actual data.
    hDrop = (HDROP) GlobalLock ( stg.hGlobal );

    // Make sure it worked.
    if ( NULL == hDrop )
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    // Sanity check - make sure there is at least one filename.
    UINT uNumFiles = DragQueryFile ( hDrop, 0xFFFFFFFF, NULL, 0 );
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    if ( 0 == uNumFiles )
    {
        GlobalUnlock ( stg.hGlobal );
        ReleaseStgMedium ( &stg );
        return E_INVALIDARG;
    }

    // Get the name of the first file and store it in our member variable m_szFile.
    if ( 0 == DragQueryFile ( hDrop, 0, m_szFile, MAX_PATH ) )
        hr = E_INVALIDARG;

    GlobalUnlock ( stg.hGlobal );
    ReleaseStgMedium ( &stg );

    return hr;
}

STDMETHODIMP CShellExt::QueryContextMenu (
    HMENU hmenu, UINT uMenuIndex, UINT uidFirstCmd,
    UINT uidLastCmd, UINT uFlags )
{
    // If the flags include CMF_DEFAULTONLY then we shouldn't do anything.
    if ( uFlags & CMF_DEFAULTONLY )
        return MAKE_HRESULT ( SEVERITY_SUCCESS, FACILITY_NULL, 0 );

    InsertMenu ( hmenu, uMenuIndex, MF_BYPOSITION, uidFirstCmd, _T("HelloExtNoAtl Test Item") );

    return MAKE_HRESULT ( SEVERITY_SUCCESS, FACILITY_NULL, 1 );
}

STDMETHODIMP CShellExt::GetCommandString (
    UINT_PTR idCmd, UINT uFlags, UINT* pwReserved, LPSTR pszName, UINT cchMax )
{
    //USES_CONVERSION;

    // Check idCmd, it must be 0 since we have only one menu item.
    if ( 0 != idCmd )
        return E_INVALIDARG;




    // If Explorer is asking for a help string, copy our string into the
    // supplied buffer.
    if ( uFlags & GCS_HELPTEXT )
    {
        LPCTSTR szText = _T("This is the simple shell extension's help");

        if ( uFlags & GCS_UNICODE )
        {   
            DWORD len;
            // Get the length (in wide chars) of the UNICODE buffer we'll need to
            // convert MyString to UNICODE.
            len = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, szText, -1, 0, 0);
            
            BSTR  strptr;

            strptr = SysAllocStringLen(0, len);
            
            // Convert MyString to UNICODE in the buffer allocated by SysAllocStr
            MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, szText, -1, strptr, len);

            // We need to cast pszName to a Unicode string, and then use the
            // Unicode string copy API.
            lstrcpynW ( (LPWSTR) pszName, (LPWSTR)(strptr), cchMax );

            SysFreeString(strptr);
        }
        else
        {
            // Use the ANSI string copy API to return the help string.
            lstrcpynA ( pszName, (LPSTR)szText, cchMax );
        }

        return S_OK;
    }

    return E_INVALIDARG;
}

STDMETHODIMP CShellExt::InvokeCommand ( LPCMINVOKECOMMANDINFO pCmdInfo )
{
    // If lpVerb really points to a string, ignore this function call and bail out.
    if ( 0 != HIWORD( pCmdInfo->lpVerb ) )
        return E_INVALIDARG;

    // Get the command index - the only valid one is 0.
    switch ( LOWORD( pCmdInfo->lpVerb) )
    {
    case 0:
        {
            TCHAR szMsg [MAX_PATH + 32];

            wsprintf ( szMsg, _T("The selected file was:\n\n%s"), m_szFile );

            MessageBox ( pCmdInfo->hwnd, szMsg, _T("HelloShlExt"),
                MB_ICONINFORMATION );

            return S_OK;
        }
        break;

    default:
        return E_INVALIDARG;
        break;
    }
}
```

```cpp
STDAPI DllRegisterServer( VOID )
{
    INT i;
    HKEY hKey;
    LRESULT lResult;
    DWORD dwDisp;
    TCHAR szSubKey[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szCLSID[MAX_PATH];
    TCHAR szModule[MAX_PATH];
    LPWSTR pwsz;

    // get the CLSID in string form
    StringFromIID( CLSID_HelloExtNoAtl, &pwsz );

    if( pwsz )
    {
        WideCharToLocal( szCLSID, pwsz, ARRAYSIZE(szCLSID) );
        LPMALLOC pMalloc;
        CoGetMalloc(1, &pMalloc);
        if( pMalloc )
        {
          pMalloc->Free(pwsz);
          pMalloc->Release();
        }
    }

    // get this DLL's path and file name
    GetModuleFileName( g_hInst, szModule, ARRAYSIZE(szModule) );

    // CLSID entries
    REGSTRUCT ClsidEntries[] = {  
        HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TEXT("CLSID\\%s"),                  NULL,                   TEXT("HelloExtNoAtl"),
        HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TEXT("CLSID\\%s"),                  TEXT("InfoTip"),        TEXT("HelloExtNoAtl."),
        HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TEXT("CLSID\\%s\\InprocServer32"),  NULL,                   TEXT("%s"),
        HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TEXT("CLSID\\%s\\InprocServer32"),  TEXT("ThreadingModel"), TEXT("Apartment"),
        HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, TEXT("CLSID\\%s\\DefaultIcon"),     NULL,                   TEXT("%s,0"),
        NULL,              NULL,                               NULL,                   NULL};

    for( i=0; ClsidEntries[i].hRootKey; i++ )
    {
        // create the sub key string.
        wsprintf( szSubKey, ClsidEntries[i].lpszSubKey, szCLSID );
        lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(  ClsidEntries[i].hRootKey,
                              szSubKey,
                              0,
                              NULL,
                              REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                              KEY_WRITE,
                              NULL,
                              &hKey,
                              &dwDisp );
   
        if( lResult==NOERROR )
        {
             TCHAR szData[MAX_PATH];
             wsprintf(szData, ClsidEntries[i].lpszData, szModule);
             lResult = RegSetValueEx( hKey,
                            ClsidEntries[i].lpszValueName,
                            0,
                            REG_SZ,
                            (LPBYTE)szData,
                            lstrlen(szData) + 1);
      
             RegCloseKey(hKey);
        }
        else
            return SELFREG_E_CLASS;
    }

    // Context Menu
    lstrcpy( szSubKey, TEXT("txtfile\\ShellEx\\ContextMenuHandlers\\HelloExtNoAtl"));
    lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT,
        szSubKey,
        0,
        NULL,
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
        KEY_WRITE,
        NULL,
        &hKey,
        &dwDisp);

    if( lResult==NOERROR )
    {
        TCHAR szData[MAX_PATH];
        lstrcpy(szData, szCLSID);
        lResult = RegSetValueEx( hKey,
            NULL,
            0,
            REG_SZ,
            (LPBYTE)szData,
            lstrlen(szData) + 1);

        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    else
        return SELFREG_E_CLASS;

   // register the extension as approved by NT
   OSVERSIONINFO  osvi;
   osvi.dwOSVersionInfoSize = sizeof(osvi);
   GetVersionEx( &osvi );

   if( VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT == osvi.dwPlatformId )
   {
       lstrcpy( szSubKey, TEXT("Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Shell Extensions\\Approved"));
       lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
                              szSubKey,
                              0,
                              NULL,
                              REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                              KEY_WRITE,
                              NULL,
                              &hKey,
                              &dwDisp);

       if( lResult==NOERROR )
       {
           TCHAR szData[MAX_PATH];
           lstrcpy(szData, TEXT("HelloExtNoAtl"));
           lResult = RegSetValueEx( hKey,
                                 szCLSID,
                                 0,
                                 REG_SZ,
                                 (LPBYTE)szData,
                                 lstrlen(szData) + 1);
      
          RegCloseKey(hKey);
      }
      else
          return SELFREG_E_CLASS;
   }

   return S_OK;
}
```

Comment: How is your context menu implemented? Do you have any code to show https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks, I have added the main part of the code. For the whole project, you can download it from the url.

Comment: You can change QueryContextMenu implementation and call InsertMenu or InsertMenuItem somewhere else since you have the menu handle (HMENU). That being said, your extension may be called late in the game by the Shell so other context menus will be called after you and can mess with menu item orders too... Some extensions register in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*` for that reason (like notepad++). So there's no definite solution to this problem, context menu is a hostile shared environment. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7007852/order-in-the-windows-explorer-context-menu

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. Now I'm trying to find out how OneDrive implemented it.  In the OneDrive folder, the context menu shows additional menus (like "Share", "Copy link", and "View online") above the "Always keep on this device" menu item. Do you have any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: Two main reasons: 1) OneDrive is a Cloud Storage Provider which is a special type of Windows component that the Shell knows (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/integrate-cloud-storage and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cfapi/build-a-cloud-file-sync-engine) and 2) the Shell *knows* OneDrive intimately (and the reverse is quite true too, both are developped by Microsoft) so integration is better